# Looking for a question on Anime and Manga?

Tags: support

I am looking for a question or answer on Anime and Manga which answers this question I was thinking of asking which is ***Why do animes come out at night?*** I am sure there is an answer to this somewhere or a question that asks this, and I am certain that there was a question like this on this site, but I cannot find it again.

Anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4013/why-does-anime-usually-air-at-night-in-japan

Comment: @LoganM- I knew it was around here somewhere, thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a note, if you cannot find a question on the site using the search or even Google, just ask it normally.

If it's a duplicate, we'll mark it as such, and that will make it easier to find in the future!

**[We love duplicates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)** :)